# javascript: css style call within html not working

Tags: jquery, html

hey I am trying to learn jquery and i have problem with the images not showing up when i use jquery to add a css class to a div tag here is my code

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<title>Untitled 1</title>
<script src="jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="javascript_stuff.js"></script>
<link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>
    <h1>trying to find out whats wrong with this code</h1>
    <h2>Here is the picture</h2>


<body>

<p></p>
<div class="thumbnails">
<a href="Images/User Images/early-sunrays.jpg">
<img alt="sunrays" height="75" src="Images/User%20Images/early-sunrays_thumbnail.jpg" width="75"></a>
</div>
<div class="preview"></div>

</body>
```

css code:

```
.preview{
    width:375px;
    height:375px;
    float:left;
}
.thumbnails{
    width:75px;
    height:75px;
    border:thick aqua solid;
}
```

jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.thumbnails a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var pic_full = $(this).attr('href');
        var size =(pic_full.length-4);
        var pic_prev = pic_full.slice(0,parseInt(size))+"_preview"+pic_full.slice(parseInt(size));
        pic_prev = "../"+pic_prev;
        //alert(pic_prev);
        $('.preview').html('<a href="'+pic_full+'" style="background-image:url('+pic_prev+');"></a>');
    });
});
```

This may be a stupid question but i cant seem to make it display even though the path is right and i am trying to create a css style inside html ..Any help would be appreciated.. THanks!!

Comment: can you share the fiddle.

Comment: where is (jquery to add a css class to a div tag) i dont find in your question, can you add a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `background-image: url(../img/path)`, the image path should be surrounded by quotes: `background-image: url('../img/path')`

In your case, change the last line of your javascript to:

`$('.preview').html('<a href="'+pic_full+'" style="background-image:url(\''+pic_prev+'\');"></a>');`

(Notice the escaped single quotes surrounding pic_preview).

Also, you'll probably want to change the CSS of `.preview a` to `display: block` if you're using it to show a background image.

```
.preview a {
  display: block;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  border:thick aqua solid;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vT6GC/

Hopefully that should get you started.